# Добавить постер для видео только для смартфонов

Tags: html, css, видео

Просьба подсказать, как правильно сделать, чтобы постер, добавленный к видео (в html), показывался только на телефонах и планшетах, а на компьютере было видео?

Answer (score 0):

`@media`-запросы существуют именно для таких задач. Внутри можно описать стили, которые применятся только если условие будет выполненно.

Например: mobileOnly скрыт. Но на экране 600px шириной или ниже `display:block`

```
.mobileOnly { displaly: none; }

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .mobileOnly {
    diaply: block;
  }
}
```

Документация: http://htmlbook.ru/css/value/media